# issue with windows 8 snapped view

Tags: windows-8, html5-canvas

I'm designing a game for `windows 8` using `HTML5` , but my game can't be shown in snapped view and i'm wondering if it is possible to just show an image (like : Store application )?! if so how can i do that ?!

also can i set my game not to work in snap view like looking orientation?

- i want to make it similar to the next screenshot

[image]

Comment: Um, just do it. When you detect that you're snapped, display a placeholder.

Comment: @RaymondChen i'm sorry but how to display a placeholder

Comment: Instead of drawing your game, fill the screen with green and draw an icon in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks alot for your help , i solved it as you said "detecting when the app is in the snap view and so it will appear as i set in CSS file

sample code

checking for snap view

```
window.onresize = function () {
            var myViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
            var viewStates = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState;
            if (myViewState == viewStates.snapped) 

                //do what you want


        }
```

then you should be perviously setting up your CSS file

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
//do what you want to show when app go to snap view stat
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices for changing your view for snapped. You can specify different CSS in the different media queries which should already be in your CSS, or you can do it with imperative code in the page's updateLayout event.
For what you're attempting, I would just have a div with your icon in it and a div with everything else and change the "display" property in the media queries.
Let me know if you need me to be more specific.

Comment: just want to know how to display an image like the above in
`
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
//what should i write here ?!
}`